# How can I serve external css/js files to html files displayed by a NodeJS app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I would like to serve html files at given URLs using only NodeJS, or a very lightweight and flexible other way. I've been able to serve those html pages using Express but there are things I don't like (the fact we must use a public folder and all the dependencies), and the external css/js just don't load.

I use something in the server.js file like :

`app.get('/', function() { app.sendFile('index.html')});`

And in the index.html file :

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

All the files are in the **same** folder.

Answer (score 1):

In `express` you could you `static` middleware.

In the example below you define `public` directory to store it.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Now you can put your `style.css` to this folder and it will be served as a static content.

More about middleware: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html